# Usage of 'long-awaited'

Tags: word-usage

Say the new album of my favorite artist comes out, and I've been waiting for it for a long time. In that case, is it correct to say this?

> This (the release of the new album) was long-awaited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! [*long-awaited*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/long-awaited) is a general way to express that something anticipated for *a considerable time*

See here: [one such entry](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=n0IJ8GcdJ6IC&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=%22was%20long%20awaited%22&source=bl&ots=d4gj2nnp7k&sig=ACfU3U0rxHbIUIoBZHB3hwJTK2V3k_gw8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjph_KK1u7mAhXL7nMBHQU9C4IQ6AEwB3oECB0QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22was%20long%20awaited%22&f=false)

> *The speech was long-awaited.*

Comment: thanks. and is there another way of expressing the same idea?

Comment: You could say 'much-anticipated'.